# Using elasticsearch with geometrical data (big data research)

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, bigdata

I got a huge amount of tracking data from a research study (26 Objects * 25 frames per second * 90 minutes * 50 = ~175 500 000 records in my Database).

The reference system of the tracking data is a fixed environment of x*x meters, and not a geographical lat / long system.

The schema (MySql) looks like this:

```
TABLE trackingdata:
uid(int) 
object_id(varchar)
coords(POINT(X Y)
voronoi_cell(POLYGON(...)
voronoi_area(float)
frame(int)
timekey (datetime)
```

I want to use elasticsearch to efficiently query and analyze (love kibana!) my data.

Since I don't have much experience with elasticsearch i was wondering if it can handle geometric data (POINT, POLYGON) or if it is restricted to to its gepoint-datatypes (geo**graphical**, not geometric) datatypes I found browsing the documentation ( [GeoPoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html), [GeoShape](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html) )

*Would elasticsearch be capabable of finding records by an example query like this:
"find all **voronoi_cells** that are within a rectangle described by **coords** with a specific **voronoi_area***

Comment: Can you show a sample record?

Comment: The sample record would just be a json representation of the `trackingdata` schema I posted.

Comment: I'm interested in what you have in `coords` and `voronoi_cell`

Comment: `coords` would contain a two-dimensional x/y representation of my coords (for example (`POINT(5 10)`), a `voronoi_cell` contains coords that form a polygon (for example `POLYGON((0 0, 10 0, 0 10, 0 0))`).